# Flutter animations usage Flutter animations usage

Tags: flutter, performance, animation, flutter-animation

If I am using a lot of animations in my flutter application , Does that reduce the app performance ?

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest you to start using them before wrapping your head on performance concerns, and reading some of the [docs](https://docs.flutter.dev/perf/rendering-performance) speaking about performance when using animations, when needed. A good read now won't hurt tho.

If you have practical concerns as of now, consult the [performance profiling](https://docs.flutter.dev/perf/ui-performance#:%7E:text=Flutter%20aims%20to%20provide%2060,to%20render%20approximately%20every%2016ms.) documentation page, you'll be helped identifying the performance bottlenecks of your application.